# Запись в файл кириллицей

Tags: pascal, кодировка

Программа должна записать из переменной в файл английские и русские буквы, но вместо русских пишутся какие-то каракули. Как это исправить?

Comment: Вероятно, Вы открываете текстовый файл не в той кодировке, в которой пишет Ваша программа.

Comment: А как сделать что бы она писала в той же кодировке в которой и файл?

Comment: Все зависит от того, о каких вообще кодировках идет речь. Pascal/Delphi не особо в курсе о кодировках — для них строки это не символы, а цепочки байтов. Соответственно, в какой кодировке строка в исходнике, так оно и будет записано. Возможно, есть директивы компилятора, но я не в курсе.

Comment: Если исходный файл редактируется в досовском редакторе Turbo Pascal, то его кодировка cp866, а стандартный блокнот отображает текст в кодировке cp1251. Как вариант, можно написать процедуру перекодировки текста перед выводом в файл.

Comment: А какой компилятор у вас?

Comment: Free Pascal

Comment: А редактор?

Comment: Так это же IDE, там всё вместе, редактор текста, 
компилятор, отладчик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный редактор Free Pascal хоть и не досовский, но консольный, а кодировка консоли в Windows - опять же cp866.

Если программа пишется для себя, для просмотра файла можно использовать просмотрщик или текстовый редактор, поддерживающий различный кодировки. Могу посоветовать встроенные просмотрщики Far Manager или Total Commander.

Если нужно чтобы например текстовый файл потом смог прочитать кто-то другой при помощи блокнота, то для перекодировки можно например воспользоваться функцией WinAPI [OemToChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), или написать свою, воспользовавшись информацией о кодах символов кириллицы в соответствующих кодировках: [OEM 866](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/goglobal/cc305166.aspx), [Windows 1251](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/goglobal/cc305144.aspx).